# How to install firefox add-on using Capybara & Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am trying to install an add-on on Firefox, however, I couldn't achieve it with whatever I've tried.

```rb
require 'capybara'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_proxy do |app|
  desired_caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

  # Here is the add-on I am trying to install.
  profile.add_extension('/home/user/Downloads/try_xpath-1.3.5-fx.xpi') 
  
  options.profile = profile
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    browser: :firefox,
    desired_capabilities: desired_caps,
    options: options
  })
end

browser = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_proxy)
browser.visit 'https://google.com'
```

What am I doing wrong here? The browser visits the URL without installing any add-on. I am able to install an add-on manually from the file.

Moreover, when I want to add a profile I get the error below:

```rb
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /tmp/webdriver-rb-profilecopy20200815-25523-ie6apk/lock
from /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubyzip-2.2.0/lib/zip/entry.rb:405:in `stat'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since noone has answered yet I will share how I've overcome this problem in case you want to install extensions.

*If anyone else has a better answer then I can accept their answer, so please answer if you have a better solution.*

#### 1st Method

I was just messing around with the Firefox profile folders and I figured that I could use an already existing profile folder with only the `extensions` folder in it. So I've deleted all the other files/folders in the profile folder that I wanted to use.

So basically the steps are:

- Create a Firefox profile or use an existing one.
- Install your desired add-on using the browser with the same profile.
- Close the browser.
- Navigate to the same Firefox profile folder and delete all the other files/folders in the profile folder.
- Then use the path to that Firefox profile folder when you are instantiating a `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile` like so:

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_proxy do |app|
  desired_caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new '/path/to/firefox/profile/folder/'
  
  options.profile = profile
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    browser: :firefox,
    desired_capabilities: desired_caps,
    options: options
  })
end

browser = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_proxy)
browser.visit 'https://google.com'
```

I've tried to create a folder named `profile` and inside that folder I've created another folder named `extensions` the same way Firefox does and moved all the add-ons I wanted to upload into that `extensions` folder but that didn't work.

I guess Firefox changes the add-on file when installing the add-on so downloading an add-on from [their website](https://addons.mozilla.org/tr/firefox/) and trying to use it in the profile folder doesn't work. This is my guess of course.

#### 2nd Method

You could alternatively use:

```rb
browser = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_proxy)
browser.driver.browser.install_addon '/path/to/addon.xpi'
```

I know this looks messy so you could just stop using `Capybara` and use `selenium` directly but `Capybara` has some cool methods as well.